# Chrome 100% width and 100 vw overflow

Tags: css, canvas

[Here's a repro](https://github.com/Vandivier/charm-abm/tree/vw-repro).

Padding off, margins off, I don't see what's causing the space circled below. I'm using normalize, it doesn't matter. I get that the vertical scroll bar changes things, but shouldn't 100% width fix this?

The screenshot is using canvas width, max-width 80% and the right hand is allowed to size by the browser. If I set to 20% it wraps below.

[image]

Update: For those too lazy to click the repro link, here's a similar snippet:

```css
.model-div {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}

.ui-console {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="model-div"></div>
  <div class="ui-console">
    <button class="reset" onclick="model.fReset()">Reset</button>
    <button class="blind-mode" onclick="model.fToggleBlind()">Toggle Blind Mode</button>
    <div class="log-text-div"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you update your question to include a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: And we're not lazy, we're just hesitant to follow links blindly. Anyway, if you're complaining about the space following the inline-block, there are many questions here about that one already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers detect ANY amount of whitespace as 1 space, therefore it prints a space between the two items, thus causing the second item to fall. (Unless you use a workaround.)
Possible solutions:

1.Eliminate your whitespace inside your HTML. The easiest way to do this is to use something to minify your HTML, which honestly is a good practice anyway.

2.Set the **font-size** of your parent to zero

Parent (**body**, in your example.)

```
.parent{
  font-size:0;
}
```

Children

```
.parent>*{
  font-size:16px;
}
```

3.Float the children (Bootstrap does this in v3, before it switched to flexbox.)

```
.model-div,.ui-console{
  float:left;
}
```